# Could I use CUDA timer event to compute two kernel time separately in one file?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, timer, cuda

I create two pairs of start and stop event hoping to record two kernels' time. But I just get this:

fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

the CUDA Best Practices Guide, s 2.1.2, Using CUDA GPU Timers doesn't talk about how to record two kernels' time in one program.

Comment: That is linking error, meaning you are missing a library, or have a problem in the code. Probably unrelated to the use of timers. Can you show the code section you think doesn't work and some details of how you are compiling and linking?

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments your linker error is unrelated to those recorded events. Make sure to compile with `nvcc`, make sure you got the CUDA toolkit installed, make sure the file pathes are correct and published. See [Simplest CUDA Wrapper for Beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033340/simplest-cuda-wrapper-for-beginners) for how to get started.

If you need more information on how cudaEvents work (with example code) see
[CUDA: cudaEvent_t and cudaThreadSynchronize usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801717/cuda-cudaevent-t-and-cudathreadsynchronize-usage)

Comment: CUDA: cudaEvent_t and cudaThreadSynchronize usage link is pretty helpfu.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Visual Studio 2008, you'll need to make sure you have set your project properties properly. This includes adding the appropriate libraries in Linker->Input: Additional Dependencies under the Project's Configuration Properties as well as going into Visual Studio 2008's Options dialog and adding the appropriate files under VC++ Directories. Finally, if you right click your project's name and select "Custom Build Rules" you should select the appropriate CUDA Build Rule based on your version of the CUDA Toolkit.

Comment: My code runs correctly when I used event to record one kernel. I think my project properties settings are correct.

Comment: My code is not correct because I only Synchronize one event instead of two as what the CUDA Best Practices Guide, s 2.1.2 told me to. In fact, I need to synchronize both two events.

Comment: That got it to work? Since it worked for one kernel and not the other and you got the error you did it sounds as though the kernel that gives you this error may use a call from a library that the working kernel does not need to use.